# change font color of empty uitextfield

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I have a UITextfield and when the text field is equal to "test", I want to clear out the text field and change the font color to green. The code below almost accomplishes it.

```
- (void)editingDidBegin:(id)sender {
    UITextField *txtfld = (UITextField*)sender;
    if ([txtfld.text isEqualToString:(@"test")]) {
        txtfld.text = @" ";
        [txtfld setFont:regularFont];
        [txtfld setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
}
```

The only problem is I want to change:

```
txtfld.text = @" ";
```

to:

```
txtfld.text = @"";
```

When I do that, the font color remains the original black color. If I leave it as `@" "` then the font changes to green. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Scenario: 
(1) user enters nothing in the text field and clicks the submit button - works 
(2) the submit button updates the text field with the word "test" and makes it red - works (3) when the user goes back to the text field I want the word test deleted and when the user types for all the text to green. - Doesn't work

Note: I placed my code in the event "Editing Did Begin" as i figured when the user goes to update the field it should clear the text and allow them to type in green font color.

Comment: Try change to txtfld.text = nil; The text color remains black?

Comment: The code looks just fine... I'm confused. But try first setting the color and than clear the textField. You won't be able to see it, but might fix things up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is interesting that when you set text to @"" or nil, and also set textColor in UIControlEventEditingDidBegin event handler, the textColor is not set what so ever. So the silver lining is to set textColor at a later time, also see the comments in code:

```
- (IBAction)textEditingDidBegin:(id)sender
{
    UITextField *field = (UITextField *)sender;
    if ([field.text isEqualToString:@"test"]) {
        [field setText:@""];
        [self performSelector:@selector(setColor:) withObject:sender afterDelay:0.01];
        [field setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:15]];
    }
}

- (void)setColor:(id)sender
{
    // See this line of code closely, do NOT use sender, use textField property in your view controller class
    [self.textField setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested your code. It should work. You are reverting the color elsewhere.

You can test it in a new single view project with this code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UITextFieldDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITextField *textField;
-(IBAction)checkColor:(UIButton *)sender;
@end

@implementation ViewController

-(void)checkColor:(UIButton *)sender {
    _textField.text = @"check color";
}

-(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([textField.text isEqualToString:@"test"]) {
        textField.text = @"";
        textField.textColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    }
    else {
        textField.textColor = [UIColor darkTextColor];
    }
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return NO;
}
@end
```

Comment: The interesting thing is that why it causes a reverting using @"" not @" "?

Comment: I am not sure if it should be in endediting, please find below the full scenario. Scenario: (1) user enters nothing in the textfield and clicks the submit button - works (2) the submit button updates the text field with the word "test" and makes it red - works (3) when the user goes back to the text field I want the word test deleted and when the user types for all the text to green. - Doesn't work Note: I placed the above code in the event "Editing Did Begin" as i figured when the user goes to update the field it should clear the text and allow them to type in green font color